# how to force email client to open attachment using html

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-attachments

I'm working on a email template with HTML that have a button like "print your ticket", and I would like that when the user click the button, automatically, the client open or download the attachment. Is this possible using only HTML? Are there other solution?
Regards

Comment: No. Think about the security implications if this was possible.

Comment: Indeed. Part of the reason that MS lobotomized Outho ... I mean, Outlook, was because of too-tight integration between its products causing massive gaps in security, making it easy to deploy viruses through email. Email clients are, now, much more tightly sandboxed than in the past, and MrP's suggestion is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with an attachment. You could however do this by directing the user to a remote link where the attachment was stored using a `<a href="...">Print your ticket</a>`

Comment: I already use this method, anyway I think that is the only way.